# Get-content function for powershell svn

Tags: powershell, svn

I would like to get access to file content from SVN. It's quite easy when the path is in local disc like C:\folder...\ then I can use function `get-content -path $path`.

However, when my source path is SVN URL then I can't do it. Is there any simple way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The command you look for is [`svn cat`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/cat/). You can't use [`Get-Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) PowerShell cmdlet to access remote URLs.

Comment: You're correct about `Get-Content` but there is `Invoke-WebRequest` which can pull content down from a URL.

Comment: @alroc you could also use telnet client to connect to svn server and fetch the data. Or write a custom client. But why would one bother with that when there is a command line svn.exe client that was developed for these tasks? Sounds like redeveloping the bicycle to me. :)